# Cannot get UIBeardcore GUI Extension to work on Tridion 2011SP1

Tags: 2011, gui-extensions

Trying to get the basic extension on http://tridion.uibeardcore.com/2014/02/js-overwriting/ working but so far no joy.

1. I unblocked the zip file and extracted to a location in the server.
2. Created a "UIBeardcoreExtensionResources" virtual dir under SDL Tridion 2011 > WebUI > Models to point to this folder.
3. Updated System.config `<models>` to include the right installPath, config and vdir.
4. Updated modification number in System.config and restarted IIS.

System.config update:

```
<model name="UIBeardcore.Extension.Resources">
        <installpath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Tridion\web\WebUI\Models\UIBeardcore.Extension.Resources\</installpath>
        <configuration>Configuration\UIBeardcore.Extension.Resources.config</configuration>
        <vdir>UIBeardcoreExtensionResources</vdir>
    </model>
```

IIS Update:

[image]

UIBeardcore config on Github:

https://github.com/UIBeardcore/UIBeardcore.Extension.Resources/blob/master/Configuration/UIBeardcore.Extension.Resources.config

I don't see messages in my console nor do I see the JS merged in with the main Dashboard JS.

I know I've missed something obvious!

**UPDATE**

I think the instructions will only work for Tridion 2013 as the Tridion.Web.UI.Core.Ajax.WebServiceProxy group doesnt exist in 2011.

Comment: Via your steps it does not seem to be wrong. Step 1: replace console calls with alert; Step 2: change JScriptMinifier settings (to disable it)

Comment: JScriptMinifier set to enabled="never"

Comment: Tried alerts but still nothing - the extension JS is simply not being loaded in. One thing I've spotted - are your instructions 2013 only - I'm using 2011 SP1?

Comment: Indeed! Does changing a group in extensions target from
Tridion.Web.UI.Core.Ajax.WebServiceProxy to
Tridion.Web.UI.Core.Ajax will make a difference ?

Comment: Working on a different extension, I noticed `System.config` seems to have `xmlns="http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/Configuration"` in each of the nodes. I was having a file not found issue that seemed to go away when I added the namespace.